# A basic question self-adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Why can't there exist a self-adjoint operator $T \in L(\Bbb R^3)$ such that $T(1,2,3) = (0,0,0)$ and $T(2,5,7) = (2,5,7)$. Hint is enough.

Comment: Consider inner products of $T$ adjoined to the vectors you're given.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: What is $T$ adjoined ?

Comment: I just meant $T$ multiplying one of the vectors. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $x=(1,2,3)$ and $y=(2,5,7)$. Suppose $T$ is self-adjoint and $Tx=(0,0,0)$ and $Ty=(2,5,7)$. Consider what happens to $\langle x,Ty\rangle$. (You'll want to make use of self-adjointness.)

> Note: We could have picked $y$ to be (almost) anything and let $Ty$ be any vector that is not orthogonal to $x$ and this still would have worked.